# TextRotation angle is never set in Google Sheet API

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google Sheets API v4 from Java Client. I'm trying to get format from Cell class. Everything goes fine.

#### TEXT ROTATION

I'm succeed in getting [TextRotation element](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#TextRotation) with Vertical property set but, **angle** property is never set, what ever I put on source Google Sheets document.

Whatever the angle value selected in Google Sheet App, angle property is never set.
[image: angle slector][image: 45 angle] [image: -90deg]

*I've tried to inspect returned JSON, to know if the issue is in Java Client.

But JSON REST API also never returns this property.*

Current Result:
[image: Current JSON Result].
Expected Result:
[image: Expected JSON Result]

Comment: Same thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've written a JS Library : [screen-rotation.js](https://github.com/GotanDev/screen-orientation.js) to manage all this stuff.

```js
screenorientation().change(function(){
 // My event management
});
```

It supports iOS, Android & desktop browsers

Answer (score 2):

### Issue and workaround:

When I saw [CellFormat of the official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat), I thought that the value of `textRotation` can be retrieved by the fields of `sheets(data(rowData(values(userEnteredFormat(textRotation)))))` when the method of "spreadsheets.get" is used. But when I tested this, no values are returned. So I thought that this might be a bug. And, when I searched this at the Google issue tracker, I found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146274218. From this situation, in the current stage, it seems that the values of `textRotation` cannot be retrieved by the method of "spreadsheets.get" of Sheets API.

When you want to retrieve the value of `textRotation` using a script, as a current workaround, you can achieve it using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as a wrapper. In this answer, I would like to propose the workaround.

When this workaround is reflected to the flow for your situation, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare Web Apps side. (server side)

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor. This script is for the Web Apps. This Web Apps is used as an API.

Server side: Google Apps Script

```
function doGet(e) {
  const key = "sampleKey";
  const id = e.parameter.spreadsheetId;
  const sheetName = e.parameter.sheetName;
  if (e.parameter.key != key || !id || !sheetName) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({message: "Error."})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const textRotations = sheet.getDataRange().getTextRotations().map(r => r.map(c => ({angle: c.getDegrees(), vertical: c.isVertical()})));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(textRotations)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

- Of course, you can use the access token for this situation. But in this case, as a simple setting, I use the access key instead of the access token.

4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 3. Testing.

As a simple test, when it requests to the Web Apps using a curl command, it becomes as follows. Please set the spreadsheet ID and sheet name. When the Web Apps is correctly deployed, the values are returned.

```
$ curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?spreadsheetId=###&sheetName=Sheet1&key=sampleKey"
```

Result:

The data range is used for retrieving the values. So for example, when the values are set to the cells "A1:C3" in "Sheet1", the following result is returned.

```
[
    [{"angle":30,"vertical":false},{"angle":0,"vertical":true},{"angle":0,"vertical":false}],
    [{"angle":30,"vertical":false},{"angle":30,"vertical":false},{"angle":0,"vertical":false}]
]
```

- In this case, the cells "A1, A2, B2" have the text rotation with 30 degree. And, the cell "B1" has the vertical direction.

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)
- [getTextRotations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#gettextrotations)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer. But in my case, I can not use this workaround 
- in terms of performance, I can not run 2 differents APIs for parsing a single file. especially from what I know about google app scripts performance.. 
- I have to parse many google sheet file and I can not declare an app script on each of them

And in terms of architecture, I would have to build a patch on gsheet java api client to link to this particular app scripts. Not really light & clear

Comment: @Damien C Thank you for replying. At first, I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In the current stage, your goal cannot be directly achieved by the issue which might be a bug. So I proposed a workaround. But from your replying, I could know that my proposal was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for this. But I thought that this workaround might be useful for other users. So in this case, I would like to leave my answer. If you can permit this, I'm glad.

Comment: Sure. 
On my side, I've written a small js lib